# rails:Sqlite:how to make date only with two foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

One of my database table(feedback) have 2 key

```
class CreateFeedbacks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :feedbacks do |t|
      t.string :strengths
      t.string :weaknesses
      t.string :recommendations
      t.string :rating
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :subject_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I want one user to only have one feedback for one subject.How to add code

```
def create

@feedback = Feedback.new(params[:feedback])
@feedback.user_id=current_user.id
if @feedback.save
  flash[:success] = "Welcome #{current_user.name}!"
  redirect_to @feedback 
else
  render 'new'
end
```

end

```
class FeedbacksController < ApplicationController
    def new

        @feedback = Feedback.new
        #@user = Subject.find_all_by_teacher_id(current_user.id)
        user_subject

    end

   def create

    @feedback = Feedback.new(params[:feedback])
    @feedback.user_id=current_user.id
    if @feedback.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome #{current_user.name}!"
      redirect_to @feedback 
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end

def show

    @feedback_user_all= Feedback.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)

end

def user_subject

    @course = Course.find(current_user.course_id)
  @subject = @course.subjects
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your Feedback class:

```
class Feedback < AR::Base
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: [:subject_id]}
end
```

This will throw an error if you try to try to save two different `Feedback`s with the same `user_id` and `subject_id`.

To let the user fix their submission, you should load the @subject and @course before rendering the edit form again:

```
   def create
    @feedback = Feedback.new(params[:feedback])
    @feedback.user_id=current_user.id
    if @feedback.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome #{current_user.name}!"
      redirect_to @feedback 
    else
      # Calling this method again should load the 
      # necessary instance variables for the form
      # to work properly.
      user_subject
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: And how to do with my controller?I want to tell user the feedback has been created and return to "new" page

Comment: That's exactly what you've got in your question. `if @feedback.save` will return false if two Feedbacks have the same user_id and subject_id, and it will render the 'new' page in that case.

Comment: But,it says::undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #9):



9:       <%= f.collection_select(:subject_id, @subject, :id, :name ) %>

Comment: The instance variable @subject is probably not defined. You'll need to do the same initialization steps you have in `def new` but in `def create` to get your form to work.

Comment: I don't understand why happend this.I are a student in college who first study ruby

Comment: I have post it in the above.Thanks for helping me

Comment: I have success create a feedback.But when I try to test the unique,it didn't return new

Comment: Not sure I understand. Maybe restart your app? Using the validation I gave, it should provide an error if it wasn't saved.

Comment: I have tried it but it still doesn't work. The validation is work.I can't create feedback with same User and Subject.But it can't render the 'new'

Comment: The best way to thank someone for a helpful answer is to upvote their answer and possibly accept it.